# How to remove middle character in a string in java?

Tags: java, string, character-replacement

I am trying to print the string without its middle character, but I am not getting the required output.

```
public class StringIndexEliminator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "CARS";
        int l = str.length();
        int s = (l+1)/2;
        System.out.println(l);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(str);
        System.out.println(sb.deleteCharAt(s).toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the "middle character" for a word with even number of characters?

Comment: You need to check if the length is even and if not, then doing nothing

Comment: Come on guys,  the comment in the code explains it

Comment: @Andremoniy as there is no middle character in even I should print the string as it is.

Answer (score 2):

No need to use a ***stringBufffer*** (there is no race conditions) use the StringBuilder and then remove the char at **length/2**

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
System.out.println(sb.deleteCharAt(str.length() / 2));
```

Comment: If I use this, it is giving the required output for odd length, but it should print the string as it is if it has even length

Comment: then you need to be more specific, there is no middle char in a word with even numbers!!!

Comment: This is answering the question, a condition on the length is easy to add. But the "_remove character_" part is here

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the length of the string in even or odd, and after that print the string you want.

Hope this will do what you wanted.

```
String str = "CARS";
int l = str.length();

if((l % 2) == 0){
    System.out.println(str);
}else{
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(str);
    System.out.println(sb.deleteCharAt((l-1)/2).toString());
}
```

Comment: What improvemente have you done compare to previous answers ? This is the same as [Software Engineer  answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44132427/4391450).